# Hide Div show another using LI href

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, hide, show

need a little help in hiding/showing divs. I know there were a few posts on here but none that specifically targeted what I am looking to do.

My code is below. What I would like to do is have the corresponding DIV display when it is clicked on from the leftColum LI.

```
<div id="leftColumn">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Painting</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Landscaping</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Kitchen</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">What's next?</a> </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  <div id="rightColumnPainting">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="rightColumnLandscaping">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/paint1.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/paint2.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/paint3.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/paint4.jpg" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="rightColumnKitchen">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/yard1.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/yard2.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/yard3.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/yard4.jpg" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <div id="rightColumnNext">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house2.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house3.jpg" /> </li>
          <li> <a href="painting.html"></a><img src="./img/house4.jpg" /> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to hide the `div ul` elements, and then use the `:target` selector to `display: block`:

```
#leftColumn {
    display: block;
}

#leftColumn ul {
    display: block;
}

div ul {
    display: none;
}

div:target ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You do, of course, need to ensure that the `#leftColumn` ul is visible first; and, further, requires that the `a` elements by which you're navigating within the page has the appropriate `id` within it's `href` attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#rightColumnPainting">Painting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rightColumnLandscaping">Landscaping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rightColumnKitchen">Kitchen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#rightColumnNext">What's next?</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lks3G/2/).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! If you feel your question has been suitably answered, please consider accepting the/an answer. =)

Comment: when I use this method - my page "jump" to the target location, is there a way to turn that off? If not, how would I go about executing this with jQuery?